# Dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have two HDDs for my HP notebook, one has Windows 7 and the other has Ubuntu. I physically change hard disks when I want to use Windows or Ubuntu. I was thinking to put Ubuntu in an HDD caddy and replace the optical drive.

Will I need to modify the boot loader? I want Windows to start as default, and when I need to use Ubuntu I will just toggle to Ubuntu.

Comment: Try to update the repository, this might helps in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything: Just ensure the Windows HD is internal and the Ubuntu is in the caddy, go to your BIOS and boot off the external HDD.

Don't try doing the reverse (which you weren't: just making sure!) as Windows 7 cannot just easily boot of an external USB drive.  Just ensure that the external caddy and your PC both support USB 3.0 to make the experience faster.

If you don't mind swapping out your DVD drive for a caddy (whenever you need Ubuntu), have a look at [this funny link](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=DVD+HDD+caddy) and you'll see what I'm taking about!  ;-)

Comment: Hi, both windows 7 and ubuntu are working however default boot is for ubuntu no matter what i change in bios or switch the HD to SD Caddy, any idea if i could make windows 7 as default and first one to start?